# Floating point exception error while counting even numbers average

Tags: c++

I am trying to find even number average with c++, my code seems to be fine, it counts everything perfectly fine, but when i input n as 2 or n as 1, i get floating point exception error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int kiekis = 0, sum = 0, vidurk = 0, n;
    cin >> n;

    if (n < 2) {
        cout << "NO" << endl;
    }

    else if (n == 2) {
        cout << n / 2 << endl;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                kiekis++;
                sum += i;
            }
        }
    }
    vidurk = sum / kiekis;
    cout << vidurk << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Go step by step through your code. You input 1 and what happens next? How many times is the loop called? What are the values of `sum` and `kiekis` when loop finishes?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
vidurk = sum / kiekis;
```

to

```
vidurk = kiekis == 0 ? sum : (sum / kiekis);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this statement

```
vidurk = sum / kiekis;
```

the values of the variables in the right side of the assignment are equal to zero

```
int kiekis = 0,sum = 0,vidurk = 0,n;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

because when n is equal to 1 or 2 the variables are not changed.

So before outputting the average you should check whether `kiekis` is equal to 0.

Comment: And how should I fix it? Because if i delete "= 0" from them, the code doesn't count the average right anymore

Comment: @xdarkestshadow For example you could check before outputting the result whether kiekis is equal to 0. Also take into account that in the expression there is used an integer arithmetic. Deckare the variable sum as having the type float.

Answer (score 0):

`vidurk = sum / kiekis;` is division by zero unless `else` runs.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the value of sum and kiekis remain 0 whenever you enter 2 or 1.
So the value of vidurk be 0/0 
The undeterminant form.. 
Just Put

vidurk = sum / kiekis;
    cout << vidurk << endl;
This statement in else block..